# How can I animate items of layer_list?

Tags: android, animation

I have layer_list 
and one of the item is vectorDrawable
I need to make animations with two layers the circle (background) should scale when the scale is finished checkmark should fade. I'm totally dummy in animations how can I solve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/light_green" />
        <corners android:radius="150dp" />
        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="30dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark" />
</layer-list>


<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="56.7"
android:viewportWidth="56.7">
<path
    android:fillColor="#010101"
    android:pathData=""/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have two separate views in separated xmls 
and you can start one and call the second when the first is finished,sorry for writing in Kotlin,but I'm sure you will get it.

```
circle.startAnimation(scale)
scale.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
  override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
  }

  override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
  }

  override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
    //start the second
  }
})
```